# How to start a foreach from a specific key and continue after that to the rest of the array?

Tags: php

I have an array that contains key-value:

```
Array
(
    [monday_deal] => 753394
    [tuesday_deal] => 753401
    [wednesday_deal] => 753435
    [thursday_deal] => 753437
    [friday_deal] => 771844
    [saturday_deal] => 15047
    [sunday_deal] => 753437
)
```

I need to start a  `foreach` that starts from the today's day deal `(key = wednesday_deal)`, for eg.
I need to know the deal ID of Wednesday first and then continue to get the deal IDs of Thurdsay, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday serially.

NOTE: I wish to use `foreach` and not `for` since I have to make use of `$key` and `$value` combinations further in the code.

Comment: Use `array_keys()` to get an array of the keys. Then you can loop over the indexes, and use that to get the key from the key array and the corresponding value from the original array.

Comment: I dont know php but doesnt for "each" specify, that every element gets visited?

Comment: @xtay2 I want to visit each but first I want to visit a specific key and then the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_search on the keys to find the position of your key and then use array_slice to return the relevant part of the array. If you only need the deal ids, use array_values on the result, if you need more, use it in foreach.

```
<?php
    $data = [
       'monday_deal' => 753394,
       'tuesday_deal' => 753401,
       'wednesday_deal' => 753435,
       'thursday_deal' => 753437,
       'friday_deal' => 771844,
       'saturday_deal' => 15047,
       'sunday_deal' => 753437,
    ];
    
    $pos = array_search('wednesday_deal', array_keys($data));
    if ($pos===false) {
       //error
    }
    
    $resultArray = array_slice($data, $pos);
    
    //either
    $resultDeals = array_values($resultArray);
    $firstDeal = $resultDeals[0];

    
    //or
    foreach ($resultArray as $key=>$value) {
       echo "$key => $value";
    }
```

Of course if Wednesday deal is always at 3rd position, you can skip the array_search

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't start back from Monday after you reach Sunday.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you only have to change one line for that - with a second array_slice.